# Is the inverse nakayama functor zero on non injectives if the quiver has no relations and no cycles?

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

I tried a lot of examples and the inverse nakayama functor $\nu^{-1}$ seems to be zero on non injective represetantions for all quivers I tried. Of course this is false if the quivers has relations (as I learned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062510/why-is-the-auslander-reiten-theory-not-working-in-this-example) ). But in the case of a quiver with no relations it seems to be always zero on non injectives. I even proved it for any quiver of the form $\mathbb{A}_n$ using a rudimentary method of studying the possible morphisms between an indescomposable injective $I(k)$ and any non injective indescomposable representation. And I think that the same is true for any quiver $\mathbb{D}_n$ but the proof seems way more complicated.

Does this hold in general for quivers with no relations (and possibly no cycles)?

Answer (score 2):

In quivers with no relations and cycles, the inverse Nakayama functor $\nu ^{-1}$ maps indecomposable noninjective modules to zero. And it maps indecomposable injective modules to the corresponding indecomposable projective modules. For example: quiver $Q: 1 \rightarrow 2$, then $\nu ^{-1}(S(2))=0$ and $\nu^{-1}(S(1))=P(1)$, so $\nu^{-1}(S(1) \oplus S(2))=P(1)$

Comment: Thanks! how can I prove it though?

Comment: Note that quivers with no relations and cycles are hereditary algebras(submodules of projective modules are still projective). If $f: M \rightarrow P$ is a nonzero morphism from an indecomposable module $M$ to a projective module, then $M$ is projective. So $Hom(-,A)$ maps nonprojective indecomposable modules to zero, then $\nu =DHom(-,A)$ the same. Similarly, we get $\nu^{-1}$ maps noninjective indecomposable modules to zero.  You can also see the book quiver representations by Ralf Schiffler.